# Rails 3 HABTM query with array, need AND not OR/IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Say I have two models with a HABTM relationship. Teacher and Student. Here is an example of what I currently have working:

```
student_ids = [1,2,3,4]

Teacher.joins(:students).where("students.id" => student_ids)
```

The problem is that this will return all Teacher objects with with ANY of those student ids, but not require ALL of them:

```
SELECT `teachers`.* FROM `teachers` INNER JOIN `students_teachers` ON `students_teachers`.`teacher_id` = `teachers`.`id` INNER JOIN `students` ON `students`.`id` = `students_teachers`.`student_id` WHERE `students`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I have two cases, one of which is an OR condition, which the above handles fine since I just need to find Teachers with Student.id 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4. The other is AND, where I need to ensure that the the Teachers being returned include ALL of the student_ids, so Teachers with Student.id 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an include

example here:

```
 clients = Client.includes(:address).limit(10)
```

this is what would happen:

```
SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10
SELECT addresses.* FROM addresses
WHERE (addresses.client_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

you can read more about it here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the actual issue though, which is being able to collect clients that meet all conditions of an array passed in. So not just saying where the client_id is in the array, but making sure the client_ids (since it's a habtm relation) include all elements in the array.

Comment: try this. adjust the code for your situation.                     @forums = Forum.joins(:forum_tags).where(:forum_tags => {:name => @tags}).group("forums.id").having(['COUNT(*) = ?', @tags.length]).includes(:forum_tags).all

Comment: I'm able to get is working a bit by using Teacher.joins(:students).where(:students => {:students => student_ids}).group("teachers.id").having(['COUNT(*) = ?', student_ids.length]).includes(:students) 

The issue is now that I am building and ActiveRecord::Relation with a couple of these chained together. It doesn't end up giving me any results because I'm getting something like: HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND COUNT(*) = 3 at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
teachers = nil # so it wont be used in the first pass
Student.include(:teachers).where(id: student_ids).each do |student| 
  teachers = (teachers || s.teachers) & s.teachers
end
```